# Transform control in WinRt

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

I have several boxes from type Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Control with different sizes. I wanna transform a few of them vertically. Like shown in the picture.
[image]

I'm struggling doing this.I'm sure that should not be very difficult but I don't get it...
Btw. I wanna do that in code behind not in XAML.

Many thanks for your help.

Cheers
Daniel

edit:

```
            DoubleAnimation scaleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
            scaleAnimation.From = startHeight;
            scaleAnimation.To = this.ClientHeight * Percentage;
            scaleAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500);
            scaleAnimation.EasingFunction = new QuarticEase() { EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseOut };
            Storyboard storyScaleX = new Storyboard();
            storyScaleX.Children.Add(scaleAnimation);

            Storyboard.SetTarget(storyScaleX, slice);

            scaleAnimation.EnableDependentAnimation = true;
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(storyScaleX, "Height");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply a `TranslateTransform` to the `LayoutTransform` or `RenderTransform` of the element (depending on what you need). e.g.

```
element.LayoutTransform = new TranslateTransform(0, 100)
```

If the effect you require depends on the height of the element, use the element's `ActualHeight` as the value to translate by.

Comment: please see edit. The height is bounded to an animation.